# What is the procedure finding the Orthogonal Basis of a Quadratic Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

We have the following quadratic form:

$$q := 6 x^2_1 + 3 x^2_2 + 3 x^2_3 - 4 x_1 x_2 + 4 x_1 x_3 - 2 x_2 x_3$$

whose eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=2$ and $\lambda_3=8$

I am not really sure how could we get the procedure to find the orthogonal basis for this form... 
For now, I know two things:
1. The Orthogonal Basis of the quadratic form was assumed randomly
2. Somehow we used some sort of "Witchcraft" from the eigenvectors.

Which one is true

Comment: This might be helpful: https://batty.mullikin.org/quadratic.pdf

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: Isn't a quadratic form a polynomial? How can it have eigenvalues? If you're referring to the symmetric matrix one can use to write the quadratic form, please mention it.

Comment: After I read my notes, I realised that I have to use the Gram-Schmidt process
Much obliged @amd

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure exactly what it is you’re asking here. There are a couple of ways that you can find an orthogonal eigenbasis.

One way is to go through the normal process of finding a basis for each eigenspace. The eigenspace of $2$ will be two-dimensional, so orthogonalize the basis that you found for it using the Gram-Schmidt process.

Alternatively, recall that the eigenspaces are pairwise orthogonal, so since the ambient space is three-dimensional, the eigenspace of $2$ must be the orthogonal complement of the eigenspace of $8$. Find an eigenvector for the latter, generate a vector that’s orthogonal to it (I hope you can do at least that), and then take the cross product of these two vectors to complete the basis.